# Make a TextArea grow with TextHeight in JavaFX (Rows/Lines)

Tags: java, javafx, textarea, chat, expand

I have been trying to make the TextArea grow with its content, for exmaple:

There is one Line in the Text area, now the user keeps writing and reaches the TextArea's right border and the text wraps, now he does have a second line (which is not wrapped by simply using '\n' internally) and I now want the text field to grow for the height of one more line.

What I have tried already:

This

```
Text text = textArea.lookup(".text").getLocalBounds.getHeight()
```

always returns the same, no matter how much Lines i do have.

This

```
textArea.getPrefRowCount()
```

always returns

> 1

no matter how much lines I have.

How can I achieve this? If someone wants a working example, Skype has that kind of mechanism in its chat.

Comment: Did you test [TextArea.wrapText](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextArea.html#wrapTextProperty)?

Comment: I am wrapping the text already but that has nothing to do with the textareasize, i want to change the height not the width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
Text text = (Text) textArea.lookup(".text");
textArea.setPrefHeight(text.boundsInParentProperty().get().getMaxY());
```

works but is not very nice since the scroll bars keep bugging.

Answer (score -1):

Should not be too hard to do it. I think you will probably have to `@Override` the `setPreferredRowCount()` method of `textArea` to return the number of rows based on what you need, or on a fixed value.

This is a common "issue" u can encounter on any `Swing` component such as `JFrame, JPanel, JLabel, JButton`, etc.

Also on these components too it is highly recommended to override the *preferred* methods in order to correctly resize them, instead of using `setBounds`.

Also maybe the `setPreferredRowCount()` method won't update herself so you would probably have to call it in a loop (or a Thread but I'd rather not) to make sure your sizes are always updated. Something like:

EDIT:

```
while(inputNeeded) {
    if(textArea1.textChanged) {
        if(text1.length > 10) {
            textArea1.setPreferredRowCount(3);
        } else if(text1.length > 20) {
            textArea1.setPreferredRowCount(4);
        }
    }
}
```

... and so on. My bad, you don't really have to override anything. Just try to use a loop like this.

Comment: I am not really sure what i have to do according to what you just said.

Comment: SetPrefferedRowCounts takes an integer as argument, i havent been that deep into java dont know too much about chaning the core of components

Comment: Well like that it wouldnt work, not every letter in every fotn ahs the same width, and also not evrey user has the same font size in their system, i'd like to do this a more proffesional way ^^

Comment: Take out all the `setBounds` and other manual sizing codes. And it should work

Comment: Got it now. Keep searching :)

Comment: Let us say the window has a width of 200px and text area of 160px, now the user changes the window size to 240px and the textareas size automatically changes to 200px, that means the number 10 wouldnt be right anymore (for exmaple the 10)  and you'd also have to be careful because of the system default font / font size