How to adjust size of RichTextArea to it's content height?
Im trying to develop a Messenger/Telegram chat app using JavaFX.
Due to the lack of support for emoji rendering by default TextArea I was forced
to look for some other solution. RichTextArea from Gluonhq solves this issue, but I struggle to adjust height of this component to number of lines of texts that it's **Document **object stores.
I noticed that I can have a pretty accurate control over its height by directly setting prefHeight, but that's all. I dont know to what i should bind this property to get the desired behaviour.
    public void setMessage(String message) {
        richTextArea.setPrefHeight(120);
        Document document = new Document(message);
        richTextArea.getActionFactory().open(document).execute(new ActionEvent());
    }


I posted in a link below a solution that works well with default TextArea. Unfortunatelly RichTextArea from Gluonhq is not based on this component either by inheritence or composition
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38684944/make-a-textarea-grow-with-textheight-in-javafx-rows-lines

I found really ugly solution. Here i posted an answer about doing the same, but with the default TextArea
So I create invisible responsive TextArea like in that answer. Its existence is only to obtain a desired height of the message. Then we save height, delete it from parent node and replace it with RichTextArea with calculated height.
    heightCalculation = new CompletableFuture<>();
    TextArea textArea = new TextArea();
    textArea.getStyleClass().add("message-text");
    textArea.setEditable(false);
    textArea.setWrapText(true);
    textArea.setVisible(false);
    messageContentContainer.getChildren().add(textArea);
    setupTextAreaDimensionsChangeEventListener(textArea);
    textArea.setText(message);
    heightCalculation.thenAccept(calculatedHeight -> {
        messageContentContainer.getChildren().remove(textArea);
        Document document = new Document(message);
        RichTextArea richTextArea = new RichTextArea();
        richTextArea.setEditable(false);
        richTextArea.setMinHeight(calculatedHeight);
        richTextArea.setPrefHeight(calculatedHeight);
        richTextArea.setMaxHeight(calculatedHeight);
        richTextArea.getActionFactory().open(document).execute(new ActionEvent());
        richTextArea.getActionFactory().save().execute(new ActionEvent());
        messageContentContainer.getChildren().add(richTextArea);
    });

Message bubble, area between grey horizontal separators is a RichTextArea
